# Graph rendering bug on Stack overflow

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation-graph, safari, page-rendering

I just found on this  [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false)

[image]

Comment: Presumably this is seen with Safari on Mac? What versions? Does a reload still show it?

Comment: No repro on IE11, chrome or FF 26 on win7 x 64. I **can repro** on safari 5.1 win x64 even after refresh.

Comment: Norepro on Konqueror 4.8.5 / Kubuntu 12.04, either. This looks like a very Safari-specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a browser's issue because when I check this in another browser like **Mozilla** and **chrome** it was not as showing as in **safari** browser.